# TYPO3 extension key

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typo3-tca

I am writing TYPO3 extension and inside main method of extension I need to get absolute path of extension so I have this piece of code:

```
...    
$extPth = t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY);
$tempUploadPth = $extPth.'/res/uploads';
return $tempUploadPth;
...
```

However, when I run the page, TYPO3 returns this error message:

> "TYPO3 Fatal Error: Extension key "" was NOT loaded!"

In the EM I have configured extension key, and here are the properties from

> localconf.php

It is notable two lines refering to same property are duplicate - and I don't know how did that happen. I didn't enter them manually.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList'] = 'info,perm,func,filelist,about,tsconfig_help,context_help,extra_page_cm_options,impexp,sys_note,tstemplate,tstemplate_ceditor,tstemplate_info,tstemplate_objbrowser,tstemplate_analyzer,func_wizards,wizard_crpages,wizard_sortpages,lowlevel,install,belog,beuser,aboutmodules,setup,taskcenter,info_pagetsconfig,viewpage,rtehtmlarea,css_styled_content,t3skin,t3editor,reports,felogin,form,introduction';

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList'] = 'extbase,css_styled_content,info,perm,func,filelist,about,tsconfig_help,extra_page_cm_options,impexp,sys_note,tstemplate,tstemplate_ceditor,tstemplate_info,tstemplate_objbrowser,tstemplate_analyzer,func_wizards,wizard_crpages,wizard_sortpages,lowlevel,install,belog,beuser,aboutmodules,setup,taskcenter,info_pagetsconfig,viewpage,rtehtmlarea,t3skin,t3editor,reports,felogin,form,introduction,rsaauth,saltedpasswords,fluid,version,workspaces,scheduler,linkvalidator,automaketemplate,realurl,tt_news,indexed_search,wt_spamshield,jquerycolorbox,kickstarter,player_profile,sponzorstvo_amer';    // Modified or inserted by TYPO3 Extension Manager. Modified or inserted by TYPO3 Core Update Manager. 

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList_FE'] = 'extbase,css_styled_content,install,rtehtmlarea,t3skin,felogin,form,introduction,rsaauth,saltedpasswords,fluid,version,workspaces,automaketemplate,realurl,tt_news,indexed_search,wt_spamshield,jquerycolorbox,kickstarter,player_profile,sponzorstvo_amer';    // Modified or inserted by TYPO3 Extension Manager.
```

As you can see last two lines have key "sponzorstvo_amer" entered, and I still don't know why I get this error when using global variable $_EXTKEY

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, `$_EXTKEY` is not defined ?

If we will check classical tt_news extension, in the begining we could see the manual definition of the extension key :

```
... 
var $extKey = 'tt_news'; // The extension key.
...
```

So, it's seems what in the plugin context the `$_EXTKEY` should not be used, as it's possible in `ext_tables.php`, for example.

Comment: I did it this way, manually defined $extKey, so helper function now returns correct path!

Answer (score 1):

In *__wizicon.php, I was using referring file with

```
$llFile = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($extKey) . 'Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml';
```

And $extKey was not set to value before using it.

I had replaced it with extkey value eg 'tt_news' and it solved the error for me. So now it is

```
$llFile = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('tt_news') . 'Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml';
```

Answer (score -1):

How have you named your extension folder? Folder Name = Extension Key. If that doesn't match, TYPO3 will throw this exception.

What you do within your Extension Code should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Extension dir is also named "sponzorstvo_amer" so it doesn't seem like naming problem.